# After Natty 11.04 installation system won't boot

Tags: 11.04, boot, grub2, screen

my notebook is an Acer Extensa 2902LMi with following components:
Pentium M 715
Intel 855PM chipset
Intel PRO/Wireless 2200BG
ATI MOBILITY RADEON 9700 64 VRAM
512MB RAM

I run Ubuntu 10.04 LTS for month without any problems on my notebook.
Now I want to upgrade to Ubuntu 11.04.
I booted from the Ubuntu 11.04 LiveCD without any problems. Everything was working stable.
So I decided to install Ubuntu 11.04 to my harddisk.
The installation process run without any problems too.

But after installation was finished and the reboot came, the system hangs after GRUB was loaded with a black screen an the flashing cursor in the top left corner.

When I choose Recovery Mode in Grub I get some pages with logs scrolling very fast and ended with "Fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed!"

If I add "acpi=off" to Grub, the system starts and I can use Unity as well.
But now I don't have acpi features and my wireless card is not detected, too.
So anybody now what the problem could be?

Comment: I've got a similar problem. It only boots when using the older 2.6.35 kernel from maverick. I don't see a flashing cursor though.

Answer (score 1):

having same problem. probably issue of radeon video card. you can boot with radeon.modeset=0 option instead of acpi=off, and look what features are shrinked in this case

everything works fine on kernel 2.6.35 so you might want to downgrade to it. i'm running 11.04 on this kernel on my acer 5180T and so far no problem